# need to create a configureable timer task in java via XML

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, timertask

I have a multi threaded socket server application. My requirement is to update a table every X min which i do now by running a parallel thread. The duration(in minutes) is stored in a XML file. but the parallel running thread is taking too much space on the heap memory, ultimately causing an OutOfMemoryError.
Below is the code for the updation.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{ 
public void run()
   {
        while(true)
        {
            int TOmin=0;
            int timeout=0;
            try {

                TOmin=Integer.parseInt(DatabaseManager.getSMSTimeout().trim()); //the method reads from a XML file.
                timeout=TOmin*60*1000;
                Thread.sleep(timeout);
                DataManager.callstoredprocedure();

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                LogManager.logException(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                LogManager.logException(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
            }

        }

    }
 }
```

I looked into the [Scheduled Executor Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) but unable to configure the delay prameters from a XML file. Please suggest a way to do the task without causing leaks in memory.

**EDIT-1**- using spring core is not an option and i have to work it with threads only. Any suggestions.

Comment: Most probably you have lots of rows in the database and trying to read them all into the memory at once. Try them row by row, or using a stream.

Comment: Have you tried using Quartz Scheduler: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/?

Comment: @abbath No that is not the case. only the top 1 row is updated.

Comment: @BorisPavlović Cannot have a lot of dependencies on the app. It is simple core java based socket server. Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Go with Spring core and use:

```
 @Scheduled(<Options>)
```

its to much easy you can make a jar and run it will run perfect. so no need to work with thread , thread always makes to difficult to manage

http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/

Comment: Don't know what that is.